# When $|f|$ and $\arg(f)$ are analytic?

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $f:ℂ→ℂ$ be an analytic function.
Define $|f|$ and $\arg(f)$ be the modulus and the argument of $f$. Generally, $|f|$ and $\arg(f)$ are not analytic.

My question is about the cases where this happen: $|f|$ and $\arg(f)$ are analytic.

Comment: Only if $f$ is constant http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem

Comment: But there exists some cases where $|f|$ **or** $arg(f)$ are analytic.

Comment: @RH1: If even one of them is analytic it must be because $f$ is constant.

Comment: I changed $arg(f)$, coded as arg(f), to $\arg(f)$, coded as \arg(f).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values of a nonconstant analytic function defined on some domain $\Omega\subset{\mathbb C}$ always fill another two-dimensional domain $\Omega'\subset{\mathbb C}$. Given an analytic $f:\ \Omega\to{\mathbb C}$ the two functions $|f|$ and $\arg(f)$ are real-valued, resp. $S^1$-valued; therefore they cannot be analytic.

There is, however, a way to introduce these two functions into the analytic realm: Assume that $\Omega$ is simply connected and that $f(z)\ne0$ for all $z\in\Omega$. Then there is an analytic  function $z\mapsto g(z)$ such that
$$f(z)=e^{g(z)}\quad (z\in\Omega)\ .$$
This function $g$ can be considered as the logarithm of $f$. Going through the details you will see that in fact
$$g(z)=\log\bigl|f(z)\bigr| + i \arg\bigl(f(z)\bigr)\quad (z\in\Omega)$$
(note that $g$ is only determined up to an additive multiple of $2\pi i$). So you can say that $\arg\bigl(f(z)\bigr)$ is the imaginary part of $\log\bigl(f(z)\bigr)$.